# When I upload song in sound cloud I got an error

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, upload

I am trying to upload song on Soundcloud from admin panel using the following code which is working properly with Godaddy. And my song successfully add to the soundcloud. While the same code will give me an error when executing from AWS ec2 server. I got the below error :

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2016 12:29:40 GMT
Server: am/2
Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Length: 142
```

I'm using this below code:

```
 $soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud($clientId, $clientSecret, 'your_call_backurl');
               $access_token = getToken();
               $soundcloud->setAccessToken($access_token);
               //$tracks = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me/tracks'), true);

               if($files_arr['audio_img']['error'] == 0){
                   $mytrack = array(
                       'track[title]' => $post_arr['audio_title'],
                       'track[asset_data]' => '@'.$files_arr['audio_file']['tmp_name'],
                       'track[artwork_data]' => '@'.$files_arr['audio_img']['tmp_name'],
                       'track[sharing]' => 'public'
                   );
               }else{
                   $mytrack = array(
                       'track[title]' => $post_arr['audio_title'],
                       'track[asset_data]' => '@'.$files_arr['audio_file']['tmp_name'],
                       'track[sharing]' => 'public'
                   );
               }
               //echo "<pre>";print_r($mytrack);exit;
               $track = json_decode($soundcloud->post('tracks', $mytrack,array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false)),true);
               //echo "<pre>";print_r($track);exit;
               $query_arr = array();
               $query_arr['audio_name'] = $post_arr['audio_title'];
               $query_arr['audio_url'] = $track['stream_url']."?client_id=".$clientId;
               $query_arr['track_id'] = $track['id'];
               date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
               $query_arr['added_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
               if($post_arr['show_div'] == 1 && $post_arr['audio_album'] != ""){
                   $query_arr['album_id'] = $post_arr['audio_album'];
               }
               $id = insert('audio',$query_arr);
```